# Unable to run mongo commands inside a shell for a docker instance

Tags: mongodb, docker

Following the steps mentioned in the official docs in Docker Hub for Mongo.

I am able to build everything as expected by first pulling the relevant images and then running docker-compose up command against following file.

It starts up without issues and also able to open the shell via the command below.

But in that shell, running something like **show dbs** which is a Mongo command is not recognized.

Am I missing any further setups for this? Please advice. Thank you.

My docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3.1"

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo-instance-1
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    container_name: mongo-express-instance-1
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
```

I then open the shell via following command which opens the bash terminal.

```
docker exec -it mongo-instance-1 bash
```

But Mongo commands not recognized in there as follows.

Ran following command

```
show dbs
```

Error output

```
bash: show: command not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in bash at this stage.

You need to enter mongo via following command.

```
mongo admin -u root -p example
```

Now try running your show dbs command which will work. Good luck.

```
show dbs
```

Answer (score 14):

mongo has been renamed to mongosh - this works for me

```
docker exec -it mongo-instance-1 mongosh
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. I was trying 
mongo -u root -p root but it said
"command not found".

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the mongo client from the container instead of the bash shell:

```
docker exec -it mongo-instance-1 mongo
```

And then the commands ...

Answer (score 0):

Use this command in your terminal,

```
docker exec -it mongo-instance-1 mongosh -u root -p example
```

or after the bash terminal opens try

```
mongosh -u root -p example
```

for more info see this link https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/